# Using OSMBuildings in Vue.js with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am currently working on building a GIS system using Leaflet in Vue.js and am attempting to integrate OSMBuildings to incorporate 3D models. However, it seems that OSMBuildings does not have a specified file entry point.

I have specified the file entry point as "OSMBuildings-Leaflet.js"
 `"main": "dist/OSMBuildings-Leaflet.js",`
and used the following

main.js

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'osmbuildings';
Vue.L = Vue.prototype.$L = L
```

app.js

```
var osmb = new OSMBuildings(map)
  .date(new Date(2015, 5, 15, 17, 30))
  .set(JSON.parse(geojson))
  .click(function (id) {
    console.log('feature id clicked:', id);
  });
```

However, I am encountering an error:

> OSMBuildings is not defined."

What is the issue?